# EmailJs and Form Validation problem, in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, email, notifications

In my contact form I have added a validation option and then connected to the emailjs library for email notification. However in my contact form it sends email first and then validates the form later.

How can I set it to first validate the form and then send email notifications with the emailjs library?

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  /*==================================================================
  [ Validate ]*/
  var name = $('.validate-input input[name="name"]');
  var email = $('.validate-input input[name="email"]');
  var subject = $('.validate-input input[name="subject"]');
  var message = $('.validate-input textarea[name="message"]');


  $('.validate-form').on('submit', function() {
    var check = true;

    if ($(name).val().trim() == '') {
      showValidate(name);
      check = false;
    }

    if ($(subject).val().trim() == '') {
      showValidate(subject);
      check = false;
    }


    if ($(email).val().trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
      showValidate(email);
      check = false;
    }

    if ($(message).val().trim() == '') {
      showValidate(message);
      check = false;
    }

    return check;
  });


  $('.validate-form .input1').each(function() {
    $(this).focus(function() {
      hideValidate(this);
    });
  });

  function showValidate(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

    $(thisAlert).addClass('alert-validate');
  }

  function hideValidate(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

    $(thisAlert).removeClass('alert-validate');
  }
})(jQuery);

function sendMail() {
  let parms = {
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    subject: document.getElementById("subject").value,
    message: document.getElementById("message").value,
  }
  emailjs.send("service_iv86ftk", "template_3j5kj6n", parms).then(alert("Email Sent!!"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be calling `sendMail()` from anywhere in your JS code. Given your description of the problem, I assume it's being invoked from another JS event handler unrelated to the validation logic, or even from the HTML directly.

To fix the problem you need to call `sendMail()` only from within the `submit` event handler, and only when the validation checks have successfully passed. Something like this:

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var name = $('.validate-input input[name="name"]');
  var email = $('.validate-input input[name="email"]');
  var subject = $('.validate-input input[name="subject"]');
  var message = $('.validate-input textarea[name="message"]');

  $('.validate-form').on('submit', function() {
    var check = true;

    if ($(name).val().trim() == '') {
      showValidate(name);
      check = false;
    }

    if ($(subject).val().trim() == '') {
      showValidate(subject);
      check = false;
    }

    if ($(email).val().trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
      showValidate(email);
      check = false;
    }

    if ($(message).val().trim() == '') {
      showValidate(message);
      check = false;
    }
    
    if (!check)
      return;
      
    sendMail(name, email, subjet, message);
  });

  $('.validate-form .input1').focus(function() {
    hideValidate(this);
  });

  function showValidate(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();
    $(thisAlert).addClass('alert-validate');
  }

  function hideValidate(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();
    $(thisAlert).removeClass('alert-validate');
  }
})(jQuery);

function sendMail(name, email, subject, message) {
  let parms = { name email, subject,  message }
  emailjs.send("service_iv86ftk", "template_3j5kj6n", parms).then(alert("Email Sent!!"))
}
```

Note that I amended `sendMail()` to accept arguments containing the information to send, which you already grabbed from the DOM, and I also removed the unnecessary `each()` loop when attaching the `focus()` event handlers.